# In which file can I find the custom CSS code I entered?

Tags: css, theme-customizer

I made a very important change in the custom CSS section in WordPress.
My question is: in which file can I find this handmade change?

Comment: did you make the change in the CMS -> Appearances -> Editor ?

Answer (score 1):

None. That data is stored in the database, it is not written to a file.

Comment: So that means, when the DB is deleted all my changes are now gone for ever...?

Comment: Yes, along with everything else in the database, like your posts and users and so forth. Make backups before deleting things.